# How can two branches be merged while keeping the files with different names but with the same/similar contents as two separate files?

Tags: git, version-control

I need the branch-merge operations on git as described below:

```
Main: -->Create file "A"-->O----------------------------->Merge-->Both "A" & "B"
                            \                              /  
Branch:                      O-->Rename file "A" as "B"-->O
```

I would like both two files, namely file "A" and "B", to be kept intact as two separate files after the merge even if the contents are unchanged or just slightlyl changed on the rename.
When I tried this once the file "A" and "B" were recognized as the differnt versions of the same file and unfortunately some conflicts occurred.

I am looking for the clues to realize this type of merge. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just crank up the rename threshold to 100% (or disable renames entirely). See the `--find-renames` (and `--no-renames`) eXtended (`-X`) options to `git merge`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Now I tried those options but the same errors kept coming up.
The error messages are like:
`CONFLICT (rename/rename): "ORIGINAL_NAME" renamed to "A" in HEAD and to "B" in "Branch".`
I initially created a file with the name "ORIGINAL_NAME". Then a new "Branch" was created. The file "ORIGINAL_NAME" on both "Main" and "Branch were renamed to "A" and "B" respectively.
Now I would like to merge those two while keeping them as separate files.

Comment: Even with `-X find-renames=100` (100% match required) you'll still find renames if there was an exact rename. Use `-X no-renames` to disable it entirely for this case. But note that a rename now presents as "delete old, create new" so if one "side" of the merge does not touch the file at all, and the other does a delete-old-create-new, Git will take the delete-old-create-new change. You won't get a conflict, just the rename-in-effect.

Comment: Doing renames on both sides, and turning off detection, results in "both sides delete old, left side creates new A, right side creates new B" and Git does not see this as a conflict either and deletes the old and creates both new files.

Comment: For all other cases where Git doesn't do what you want, do the merge, then make whatever corrections you want (either as a separate commit or before committing the merge result). Remember, Git's merely automating *most* of the work, it's not a substitute for humans using their brains.

Comment: As torek says, using `git merge --no-renames` should work, but if this is a one-time only merge, you can simply fix it by hand. Resolve the conflict by `git add`ing both `A` and `B` and then commit.

Comment: Conflicts are not things that prevent a merge. They're only things that Git can't automatically merge, and requires your attention.

Comment: Torek is correct. If you're lost on how to fix it, just remember that since you don't want A and B to merge, they simply have to put them back to the exact same state they were in before the merge commit. You can use `git checkout <hash of last Main commit> -- path/to/A` and `git checkout <hash of last Branch commit> -- path/to/B`. These will checkout the pre-merge state of A and B from their respective branches. Don't forget to include the `--` before the file paths. See `git help checkout` if you need to learn what they do.

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful comments! The command below finally worked.
`git merge -s recursive -X no-renames "Branch"`
In my case the name of directories and the files under the directories were also changed on the rename. That was probably why the strategy "-s recursive" was needed.
@torek, @joanis, @Inigo Thank you again for the very helpful advise. I will try fixing conflicts by hand in the next time when the number of target files are not so large. This time more than 900 files were renamed by an IDE. So I wanted to find the way to merge them automatically.